# Meta query doesn't remove placeholder escape before query

Tags: wp-query, query, meta-query

I have a problem when add some meta query into my mysql query.

the string that wordpress send to mysql is this:

```
   ( wpiw_postmeta.meta_key = 'pickup_address_data' AND wpiw_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73287d13e3222cc}Hamilton{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73287d13e3222cc}' ) 
      AND 
      ( mt1.meta_key = 'pickup_address_data' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73287d13e3222cc}Waikato{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73287d13e3222cc}' )
    )
  ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'deliver_address_data' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73287d13e3222cc}Auckland{83c8d5291f1d6000efc2ac8fcfe6137ecd349d5beb6c4cafd73"
```

Another problem is when I add some other meta query parameters, the query doesn't end.

Of course, the results doesn't match the queried arguments

Comment: it seems is the LIKE operator who places the md5 hash in there, but doesn't remove it after

Comment: How does your code look that leads to that SQL?